# Firebase Remote Config: The named parameter 'expiration' isn't defined

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, pubspec

The parameter 'expiration' is not defined I updated firebase remote config to 0.10.0 and I got this error in this line.

```
await _remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: Duration(hours: 5));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is updated please try this.

```
 await remoteConfig.setConfigSettings(RemoteConfigSettings(
              fetchTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),
              minimumFetchInterval: Duration.zero,
            ));
            await remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();
```